# getSupportFragmentManager() is not working in my adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to add an intent from my current fragment to another fragment.For that I've added an OnclickListener over an ImageButton in the card.

But its not Working properly, I couldn't find the fault in my code.

```
package com.example.kgb.homescreen.myaccount;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.kgb.R;
import com.example.kgb.components.UpdatedTextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyAccountsCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAccountsCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;

    public MyAccountsCardAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    private ArrayList<MyAccountsCard>cardArrayList;
    public MyAccountsCardAdapter(ArrayList<MyAccountsCard> cardData) {
        this.cardArrayList=cardData;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.accounts_card_layout, parent, false);
        ImageButton imButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView,imButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAccountsCardAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position ){
        //holder.accountBalance.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        Log.d("ABBB","haiii" + holder.accountType.getText());
        if(holder.accountType.getText().equals("Savings"))
        {
            holder.accountBalance.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        holder.accountNo.setText(cardArrayList.get(position).getAccountNo());
        holder.scheme.setText(cardArrayList.get(position).getScheme());
        holder.accountType.setText(cardArrayList.get(position).getAccountType());
        holder.accountBalance.setText(cardArrayList.get(position).getAccountBalance());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return cardArrayList.size();}

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageButton iButton;
        UpdatedTextView accountNo=(UpdatedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_no);
        UpdatedTextView scheme=(UpdatedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_scheme);
        UpdatedTextView accountType=(UpdatedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_type);
        UpdatedTextView accountBalance=(UpdatedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_bal);
        public ViewHolder(View itemView, ImageButton imButton) {

            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            iButton = imButton;
            context = itemView.getContext();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment mFragment = new CardExpandFragment();
            context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cardExpand, mFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `Intent ` .why `Fragment ` same page

Comment: First of all it will be better to handle fragment transactions in your main page.2nd as @IntelliJAmiya said why are you starting a new activity and a new fragment transaction together ?

Comment: I actually forgot to remove the intent part...I just updated the code right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to pass `FragmentManager` to your adapter constructor from your activity(or from fragment if you'r using)

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public MyAccountsCardAdapter(Context context ,ArrayList<MyAccountsCard> cardData ,FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.cardArrayList=cardData;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
```

Then call

```
Fragment mFragment = new CardExpandFragment();
fragmentManager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cardExpand, mFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just pass your activity to your adapter and use

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

But its not good idea. Use Listener in the adapter and call it in activity where you are setting the adapter.

Answer (score 4):

For those who use **kotlin** you can simply do something like this

```
val dialog = IntervModifFragment()//The fragment that u want to open for example
       val ft = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        dialog.show(ft, ContentValues.TAG)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FragmentManager fm = new CardExpandFragmentmFragment ()
               FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.cardExpand, fm, "fragment_card");
               ft.commit();
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya dude `getSupportFragmentManager` or `getFragmentManager` are methods from `FragmentActivity` or `Activity` those are not available in `Context`.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't the assign context values in ViewHolder. You are already passing context value from constructor.

```
   public ViewHolder(View itemView, ImageButton imButton) {

        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        iButton = imButton;
        context = itemView.getContext();

    }
```

You just need to do Cast your Context to AppcompatActivity. Just make sure that You are using AppCompatActivity instead of Activity and Passing the Context value from Activity in Adapter's constructor. Than only it can cast

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Fragment mFragment = new CardExpandFragment();
        ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cardExpand, mFragment).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `onClick` actions to the respective `Fragment/Activity` where the `adapter` is being used by using an `interface`. It is better to not perform the `Fragment transactions` in `adapter classes`.

As you see:

`itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

This code line indicates there is no specific `onClickListener` to the `image button`. The `click listener` you have set is for the entire item.